# switchable boxes with native JS

Tags: javascript, tabs, native, switch-statement

I have some troubles with native JS. I try to write a script for switchable boxes (wll known as "tabs").

actually i have a navigation:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and below some paragraphs:

```
<p class="box" id="home">Home text</p>
<p class="box" id="about">About text</p>
<p class="box" id="contact">Contact text</p>
```

i have to switch between the links to show the right paragraphs. actually i cannot edit HTML and CSS, everything have to work only with JS.

I got this one (it only shows the first paragraph):

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

for(i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
if (i !== 0) {
    box[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

but i have no idea how can i switch between the paragraphs. my JS knowledge is very poor^^

have anybody an idea?

Comment: is this all you code for javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check jsfiddle for a solution:

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/W8MRL/4/)

This is not a particularly reusable solution but it does what you require without the use of a library.

Comment: good answer but for `getElementsByClassName` you could also offer an alternative for older browsers it would only need a could of extra lines

Comment: Agreed, I should have mentioned a caveat there.

Comment: yes, it works. thanx Adam! but actually like I said I cannot edit HTML and have to grab links via ul-ID, so I tried this one, it works too http://jsfiddle.net/W8MRL/5/